# Здравствуйте делаю веб приложение

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Делаю веб приложение на Java c использованием:

Spring MVC
Spring Security
Hibernate

Распределение прав доступа к ресурсам/страничкам происходит через Spring Security. Есть два роль:
ADMIN
USER
Проблема -Когда USER сделал логин ему покажет всех USER-ов в том числе и его
Вопрос- как сделать чтоб когда USER сделал логин ему показал всех USER-ов кроме его?

SECURITY
 Current User

```
public class CurrentUser extends User {

private am.teletalk.teletalk.model.User user;

public CurrentUser(  am.teletalk.teletalk.model.User user) {
    super(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getUserType().name()));
    this.user = user;
}

public  am.teletalk.teletalk.model.User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public int getId() {
    return user.getId();
}
```

}

SECURITY CurrentUserDetailService

```
public class CurrentUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findOneByEmail(s);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not exist");
    }
    return new CurrentUser(user);
}
```

}

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mainPage(ModelMap map) {

    map.addAttribute("allUsers", userRepository.findAll());
    map.addAttribute("manager", new User());

    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Не вижу контроллера, отдающего всех пользователей при логине

Comment: ой извините сейчас добавлю

Answer (score 1):

Функция чтобы получить объект пользователя по текущей сессии

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
        return null;
    return (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
}
```

В самом простом варианте можно фильтрануть список

```
User currentUser = getCurrentUser();
List<User> users =  userRepository.findAll().stream().filter(u->u.getId()!=currentUser.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ну а дальнейшие улучшения, это ваша фантазия, лучше конечно создать в репозитории метод, который будет доставать всех пользователей, у которых не совпадает `Id`, но это уже вам решать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: а можно все это устроить с помощью  else if ?

Comment: в смысле отфильтровать в цикле с использованием if?

Comment: я имею в виду if(currentUser.id != user.id){
userRepository.findAll это писать в jsp

Comment: а что такое user.id?

Comment: я использую база данный MYSQL и у всех user есть уникальный id если этот idне совпадает с currentUser.id пусть печатает всех

Comment: Ну вот именно, какой этот то? Откуда вы получите user.id или вы про тот, что в базе?

Comment: да ок я понял) спасибо еще раз

Comment: прощу вам у вас есть вк? или фейсбук там могу вам дать вопрос? просто это у меня экзамен а я не очень понял

Comment: в vk по  /komdosh